# async/await syntax sometimes seemed not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i`m using Vue and wanna use async/await to give a sequence for my function A and B

```
result is false by default    

mounted() {
  this.A();
  this.B();
}

async A() {
  this.result = await this.$api...
}

async B() {
  if(this.result) let data = await this.$another1 api...
  else let data = await this.$another2 api...
}
```

i assume that after function A call api and return a value of 'result' then, function B do his job.

However, sometimes api in function B called 'another2 api' before 'this.result' get his value even if result is 'true' after function A receive a value from $api

[image: this is normal action which i expect]

this is normal action which i expect

[image]

this is an error which was found sometimes when i refresh a page.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: An async function returns a promise which can be awaited or use `.then()` to execute the second function after the first completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `mounted` as an `async`.

```
async mounted() {
  await this.A();
  await this.B();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` returns a promise.  If your `mounted()` function isn't an async function that is capable of using `await`, then you'll have to use `then`.

```
this.A().then(()=>{
   this.B();
});
```

(Sorry, the above is typescript.  You can figure out how to do the javascript... it's not my specialty at all.)

Comment: Your TypeScript snippet is the same in JavaScript.

Comment: The `this` stuff is what I've always had problems with in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the mounted method to await the first method before calling the second method. Remember to pretend mounted() with `async`.

```
async mounted() {
  await this.A();
  this.B();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mounted() {
  Promise.all([this.a(), this.b()])
         .then((res) => {
               console.log(res)
         })
}

async A() {
  const result = await this.$api...
  return result
}

async B() {
  if(this.result) {
         const data = await this.$another1 api...
         return data
  } else {
          const data = await this.$another2 api...
          return data
  }
}
```